# Linear functional in Banach space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, baire-category

Let $X$ be a Banach space, $(f_n)\in X^{*}$ a sequence with $f_n\neq 0 $ $ \forall n\in \Bbb N$. Show that there is a $x\in X$ such that $f_n(x)\neq 0 $ $\forall n$.

Need some help. Thank you!

Comment: Have you heard of Baire's theorem?

Comment: @DanielFischer yes but how will i use it? It's something with the kernel of the functionals,right?can you lead me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> It's something with the kernel of the functionals,right?

Right. What you want is an $x$ with $f_n(x) \neq 0$ for all $n$, so

$$x \in \bigcap_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \left(X\setminus \ker f_n\right) = X \setminus \bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \ker f_n.$$

The $f_n$ are continuous, so $\ker f_n$ is closed. $f_n \neq 0$, hence $\ker f_n \neq X$, and therefore $(\ker f_n)^{\Large\circ} = \varnothing$. $X$ is a Banach space, hence a complete metric space, hence Baire's theorem ...

Comment: The point is that $X$ is not the countable union of closed no-where dense sets, and therefore $X\setminus \bigcup \text{ker}f_n \ne \emptyset $ correct?

Comment: Yes. Even stronger: it is of the second category in $X$.

Comment: Right, it must be, otherwise we'd have a contradiction to Baire's Theorem. If $X \setminus \bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}} \text{ker}f_n$ were meager, then $X= \bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}} \text{ker}f_n \cup X \setminus \bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}} \text{ker}f_n$, a countable union of meagre sets contradicting that $X$ is a baire space. So conclude that $X \setminus \bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}} \text{ker}f_n$ is non-meagre or of second category.